# How do I make non-templated typedefs in the 'namespace' of a templated class?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, scope

Suppose I have this class:

```
template <typename T> class A {
    T datum;
    void foo();
}
```

I want to augment my class with the following typedef and method:

```
typedef enum {Red, Green, Blue} Color;
bar(Color color) { baz(datum,color); };
```

The thing is, I want Color to only be defined within the class, yet not be templated, i.e. I want to be able to do:

```
A<int> a;
a.bar(A::Red);
```

Now, I can't do this:

```
template <typename T> class A {
    typedef enum {Red, Green, Blue} Color;
    // ...
}
```

since it defines `A<T>::Color` for different T's, not `A::Color`. And this:

```
namespace A {
    typedef enum {Red, Green, Blue} Color;
}
template <typename T> class A { /* ... */ }
```

doesn't seem to compile. Neither does this:

```
typedef enum {Red, Green, Blue} A::Color;
template <typename A> class A { /* ... */ }
```

So, can I get an `A::Color` defined somehow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891700/c-non-template-method-in-template-class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325794/non-template-function-in-a-template-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

After the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470629/how-do-i-make-non-templated-typedefs-in-the-namespace-of-a-templated-class/31470693#comment50909544_31470693):

I think the best you can get is something along these lines:

```
template<typename T = void> class A;

template<> class A<void>{
public:
    enum Color { Red };
};

template <typename T> class A : public A<>{
      T datum;
public:
      void foo(){}
      void bar(Color c){}
};

int main()
{
     A<int> a;
     a.bar(A<>::Red);
}
```

It's a bit tricky, but all it does is to define a base `class A<void>`, that you can call also `class A<>`, that just contains the `enum`. Then you make all other template specialization inherit from this class.

I think it's the closest match to what you're looking for, i.e. a class scoped non-template `enum`.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I'm afraid you'll have to define a non template base class containing the definition of the `enum`, and then let your template class inherit from this base.

```
class A_base{
public:
    typedef enum {Red, Green, Blue} Color;
    void bar(Color color){}
};

template <typename T> class A : public A_base{
     T datum;
     void foo(){}
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a.bar(A_base::Red);
}
```

This will **not** bring the `enum` into a scope named `A`; but it will make the enum and, more important, the function `void bar(Color color)` non-templated.

Comment: But won't that mean that the template class is named `MyBase::A` and the typedef is `MyBase::Color` ?

Comment: But `bar()` uses datum... let me clarify this in the question. Or... hmm. Perhaps if we inherit `bar()`?

Comment: @einpoklum Finally, I think I got your question. Did I?

Comment: Yes, now you did. That's not so bad, I guess! I think you can drop the original answer though...